# Jmeter Beanshell couldn't recognize Set<String>

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to delete the data in `redis` before taking the sample so I put the code in Beanshell Preprocessor. But the code is not running,just like the Beanshell can not recognize the Set ,part of my code is below:

```java
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import java.util.Set;

String new_pattern = "*WITHDRAW_RISK_CONTROL_*";
Set<String> keysSet = null;
System.out.println("here****************");
```

and `Set<String> keySet =null` is not working.I have imported Set `import java.util.Set;` Is this Jmeter problem? or any reason？

The second question is :it can recognize the class `Jedis` in Jedis jar.But it can not support Jedis JedisPoolConfig ,why?

Comment: there is no problem initializing the Set.Are you getting any exceptions.If any post the stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

Beanshell does not support Generics.

You should use instead JSR223PreProcessor + Groovy instead:

- http://fr.slideshare.net/catchnkn/installing-groovy-engine-in-apache-jmeter

Note that there is a Redis DataSet if that's your request:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/

Comment: UBIK LOAD PACK,really appreciate for your help.help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

- Diamond operator was introduced in Java 7 which appeared in 2011
- JMeter comes with Beanshell 2.0b5 which was released in 2005

So it is expected that Java 7 features are not supported by quite an outdated Beanshell interpreter. It should work if you remove `<String>` bit.

[image: Beanshell set initialization]

I expect the problem lives somewhere else. In order to debug your Beanshell script you can try out the following approaches:

1. Add `debug();` directive at the very beginning of your script. It will trigger debugging information output to STDOUT (where you expect your `here****************` line)
2. Wrap "suspicious" code in [try/catch](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html) block like

   ```
   try {
       // your Beanshell
       // code here

   } catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.info("Something went wrong", ex);
   }
   ```

   Inspect *jmeter.log* file for failure details.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for advanced information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Object keysSet" instead of "Set keysSet".
It solved my problem.